# How could one construct a TLB so that not all the bits of the presented address need match to result in a hit?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, cpu-cache, virtual-memory, paging

I was wondering besides the typical matching of all bits in the presented address to the resulting page, is there another way of doing so? what are the benefits/ cons and how would one go about doing so?